# How to manually link in Brightway2 an imported exchange, given I have found the correct one in ecoinvent

Tags: brightway

I have been linking my data automatically with

```
import functools
from bw2io.strategies import link_iterable_by_fields

sp.apply_strategy(functools.partial(
    link_iterable_by_fields, 
    other=Database("ecoinvent 3.2 cutoff"),
    kind="technosphere",
    fields=["reference product", "name", "unit", "location"]
))
sp.statistics()
```

When I list the remaining unlinked datasets with

```
bw2io.importers.simapro_csv.SimaProCSVImporter
```

it outputs e.g.:

```
Electricity, low voltage {ENTSO-E}| market group for | Alloc Rec, U kilowatt hour ('Electricity/heat',)
```

Given that I found the dataset in ecoinvent:

```
'market group for electricity, low voltage' (kilowatt hour, ENTSO-E, None)
```

How do I link these datasets together?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a dataset from ecoinvent 3.2, for which bw2io does not yet have the migration data for the "special" SimaPro names. Normally conversion from Simapro names (e.g. `Electricity, low voltage {ENTSO-E}| market group for | Alloc Rec, U`) to ecoinvent activity names and reference products would be handled by the migration `simapro-ecoinvent-3`. But this doesn't work in this case:

```
In [4]: Migration('simapro-ecoinvent-3').load()['Electricity, low voltage {ENTSO-E}| market group for | Alloc Rec, U']
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
```

You can write your own migration:

```
migration_data = {
    'fields': ['name'],
    'data': [
        (
            # First element is input data in the order of `fields` above
            ('Electricity, low voltage {ENTSO-E}| market group for | Alloc Rec, U',),
            # Second element is new values 
            {
                'name': 'market group for electricity, low voltage',
                'reference product': 'electricity, high voltage',
                'location': 'ENTSO-E',
            }
        )
    ]
}

Migration("new-ecoinvent").write(
    migration_data, 
    description="New datasets in ecoinvent 3.2"
)
```

And then apply this migration to your unlinked data:

```
sp.migrate("new-ecoinvent")
```

Migration only changes the data used to link; you will still have to apply `link_iterable_by_fields` to actually link against ecoinvent 3.2.

Comment: Thank you! Everything works perfectly now. 

I see you have omitted the info "kilowatt hour ('Electricity/heat',)"